# iOS: NDK build can not found the matched jni files

Tags: java, ios, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

Run the following command in Terminal :

`user@UserMacBook-Pro androidStudio_test % java -jar project/libs/javacpp.jar -cp project/libs/javacpp.jar:project/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes com.project.mobile.jni.* -Dplatform.name=android-arm -d project/src/main/jni/proj/src/bin/sdkAndroid -cpp`

Get error message:

`zsh: no matches found: com.project.mobile.jni.*`

I have checked the folder path **com.project.mobile.jni.***, it's correct.